# calculate total salary based on employee type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to calculate the salary for each employee foe each month, so

I have two tables and two views that looks like this

Employees_View

```
| ID |  Name | PayRate | PayUnitCode | Commission |
|----|-------|---------|-------------|------------|
|  1 | James |      10 |           C |          0 |
|  2 |  Mike |   10000 |           S |          0 |
|  3 |  Jude |   20000 |          SC |          5 |
|  4 | Clara |       8 |           C |          0 |
```

Jobs

```
| id |             Created |
|----|---------------------|
|  1 | 01/21/2016 10:56:05 |
|  2 | 01/21/2016 10:56:05 |
|  3 | 01/21/2016 10:56:05 |
|  4 | 01/21/2016 10:56:05 |
|  5 | 01/21/2016 12:11:59 |
|  6 | 01/25/2016 08:03:07 |
|  7 | 11/01/2015 22:55:22 |
```

Job_Items_View

```
| Job_ID | Amount | Emp_ID |
|--------|--------|--------|
|      1 |    135 |      4 |
|      1 |    500 |      2 |
|      3 |   1500 |      2 |
|      3 |    250 |      4 |
|      4 |   1000 |      2 |
|      5 |    500 |      4 |
|      6 |    500 |      4 |
|      7 |   1000 |      1 |
```

PayUnits

```
| Code |                   Name |
|------|------------------------|
|    S |                 Salary |
|    C |             Commission |
|   SC | Salary plus Commission |
```

I have an [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4be2/1) here with data

when i execute the query

```
DECLARE @startDateTime DATETIME = '2015-11-01 00:00:00'
DECLARE @endDateTime DATETIME = '2016-02-28 23:59:59'

;WITH sales AS
(
  SELECT 
    ev.ID,
    ISNULL(SUM(jiv.Amount), 0) AS TotalSales,
    MONTH(j.Created) AS [Month],
    YEAR(j.Created) AS [Year]
  FROM Employees_View AS ev
  LEFT JOIN Job_Items_View AS jiv ON jiv.Emp_ID = ev.ID
  LEFT JOIN Jobs AS j ON j.ID = jiv.Job_ID
  WHERE j.Created BETWEEN @startDateTime AND @endDateTime
  GROUP BY 
    ev.ID,
    MONTH(j.Created),
    YEAR(j.Created)
),
commissions AS
(
  SELECT
    s.ID,
    CASE ev.PayUnitCode 
      WHEN 'C' THEN s.TotalSales * (ev.PayRate / 100)   
      WHEN 'SC' THEN (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Job_Items_View) * (ev.Commission / 100)
      ELSE 0
    END AS TotalCommission
  FROM sales AS s
  JOIN Employees_View AS ev ON ev.ID = s.ID
),
salaries AS
(
  SELECT 
    ID, 
    CASE PayUnitCode 
      WHEN 'C' THEN 0 
      ELSE PayRate 
    END AS Salary 
  FROM Employees_View 
),
totals AS
(
  SELECT 
    salaries.ID,
    ISNULL(sales.Month, MONTH(@startDateTime)) AS [Month],
    ISNULL(sales.Year, YEAR(@startDateTime)) AS [Year],
    ISNULL(sales.TotalSales, 0) AS TotalSales,
    salaries.Salary,
    ISNULL(commissions.TotalCommission, 0) AS TotalCommission
  FROM salaries
  LEFT JOIN sales ON salaries.ID = sales.ID
  LEFT JOIN commissions ON commissions.ID = sales.ID
)
SELECT 
  ev.PayRate,
  ev.Name,
  t.Salary + t.TotalCommission AS Pay,
  LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH , t.[Month], -1)), 3) 
    + '-' + CAST(t.[Year] AS VARCHAR) AS [Month],
  ev.ID AS Emp_ID,
  pu.Name AS PayUnit,
  ev.Commission
FROM totals AS t
JOIN Employees_View AS ev ON ev.ID = t.ID
JOIN PayUnits AS pu ON pu.Code = ev.PayUnitCode
```

I get

```
| PayRate |  Name |   Pay |    Month | Emp_ID |                PayUnit | Commission |
|---------|-------|-------|----------|--------|------------------------|------------|
|      10 | James |   100 | Nov-2015 |      1 |             Commission |          0 |
|   10000 |  Mike | 10000 | Jan-2016 |      2 |                 Salary |          0 |
|   20000 |  Jude | 20000 | Nov-2015 |      3 | Salary plus Commission |          5 |
|       8 | Clara | 110.8 | Jan-2016 |      4 |             Commission |          0 |
```

I expect to get

```
| PayRate |  Name |   Pay  |    Month | Emp_ID |                PayUnit | Commission |
|---------|-------|--------|----------|--------|------------------------|------------|
|      10 | James |   100  | Nov-2015 |      1 |             Commission |          0 |
|   10000 |  Mike | 10000  | Jan-2016 |      2 |                 Salary |          0 |
|   2000  |  Jude |20269.25| Nov-2015 |      3 | Salary plus Commission |          5 |
|       8 | Clara | 110.8  | Jan-2016 |      4 |             Commission |          0 |
```

For PayUnit.Code = C (Commission) , Pay = total sales * (employee.Payrate/100)

For PayUnit.Code  = S (Salary) , Pay = employee.Payrate

For PayUnit.Code = SC (Salary plus commission) , Pay =employee.Payrate + (total sales * (employee.Commission/100))

Take note of Judes pay which is 20269.25 rather than 20000 in the previous table

Comment: Include your data and explain the logic in the question itself

Comment: data has been  added

Comment: And what's the logic behind the calculation?

Comment: I added the logic in the question

Comment: Did you try breaking the into smaller pieces? To see which part doesn't work?

Comment: the only thing i noticed is that the sales CTE is not selecting the employee with `SC`. It is only joining `job_items_view` to `employee_views` on the condition that the employee id exists in the `job_items_view`

Comment: Jude's payrate in the second table should probably be `20000` instead of `2000`.

Comment: That makes sense now. Your problem is that the `WHERE` clause of that CTE drops "Jude" because that row has no "Created" dates (they're all NULL). You should probably rebuild your entire query as it is extremely complicated. It can be made much simpler, and I'd love to help but I'm on mobile so it's too difficult. A patch would be to add `OR j.Created IS NULL`, but really you should restructure this query

Comment: i would appreciate your help

Comment: How about you debug it by generating the CTEs in temporary tables instead so you can see what's in the intermediate tables. See if what is in the intermediate tables is correct. If they are then examine your final query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you exclude Jude from the sales CTE when filtering the whole joined recordset by period (despite the LEFT JOIN) and thus no commission is calculated against her record in the commissions CTE. Instead, you should apply the filter only to the jobs subset like this:

```
WITH sales AS
(
  SELECT 
    ev.ID,
    ISNULL(SUM(jiv.Amount), 0) AS TotalSales,
    MONTH(j.Created) AS [Month],
    YEAR(j.Created) AS [Year]
  FROM Employees_View AS ev
  LEFT JOIN Job_Items_View AS jiv ON jiv.Emp_ID = ev.ID
  LEFT JOIN 
  (select * from jobs WHERE Created BETWEEN @startDateTime AND @endDateTime) as j ON j.ID = jiv.Job_ID
  GROUP BY 
    ev.ID,
    MONTH(j.Created),
    YEAR(j.Created)
)
```

Here is the [updated SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4be2/45)

Comment: I want to calculate the pay for each employee for each month, the salary does not change salary earners, but should change for commission  and salary plus commission employees. try changing the dates in your query and see the error

Comment: @Smith Well, that's a different story. I simplified your query which you can find in an [updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4be2/78). If I understood correctly, you have to calculate salaries and commissions per month based on sales for the month, but even if there's some misunderstanding on my side you can use the code in the fiddle to get what you need.